# Ajax autocomplete will not work on my page

Tags: .net, ajax

I am working with the Ajax control kit to add an autocomplete to my search textbox.  I cannot get it to work using a PageMethod or a webservice on my masterpage.  I was able to create a new page not using a masterpage and it worked.  Here is my code.

Edit- I found out Page-Method does not work in a masterpage.  I am still having trouble calling the web service though.  I add a service refrence to it then add this to the extender "ServicePath="NameWebService.asmx""  I still get nothing.  I check to see if the server side is getting hit and it is not.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID ="ScriptManager2" EnableCdn="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" 
        runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CssClass="textbox" placeholder="User Name/ Full Name" 
                        runat="server" Width="200px" AutoComplete="off" />
                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="txtSearch" ServiceMethod="GetSearchResult" 
                        MinimumPrefixLength="2"  />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="buttonSubmit" Text="Search" 
                        onclick="btnSearch_Click" />

                </asp:Panel>
```

This is my page method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetSearchResult(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<Person> listPerson = Person.SearchForPerson(prefixText);
        string[] arrayNames = listPerson.Select(n => n.FullName).Take(count).ToArray();

        AbuseReport report = new AbuseReport();
        report.AbuserPersonID = -1;
        report.Message = prefixText;
        report.ReportingPersonID = -1;
        report.CreateAbuseReport();

        return arrayNames;
    }
```

This is my webservice

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class NameSearch : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetSearchResult(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<Person> listPerson = Person.SearchForPerson(prefixText);
        string[] arrayNames = listPerson.Select(n => n.FullName).Take(count).ToArray();

        AbuseReport report = new AbuseReport();
        report.AbuserPersonID = -1;
        report.Message = prefixText;
        report.ReportingPersonID = -1;
        report.CreateAbuseReport();

        return arrayNames;
    }
}  // End of Service
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to register your Webmethod in the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://www.yourdomain.com"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <services>
    <service name="Service">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

See "How to: Use Configuration to Add an ASP.NET AJAX Endpoint" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628467.aspx